# Sort a Filtered Range

Tags: sorting, excel, vba

I need to to filter this range that has already been filtered. I'm using the below code but I think that the autofilter is unnecessary. However, if you remove the autofilter, I still get a
"Run Time '438': Object doesn't support this property or method" error.

Here is my code:

```
Range(cells(1,1),cells(9,5).select
selection.autofilter
activesheet.selection.autofilter.sort.sortfields.clear
activesheet.selection.autofilter.sort.sortfields. _
    add key:=range("a8"), sorton:=xlsortonvalues, order:=xldescending, _
    dataoption:=xlsortnormal

with activesheet.autofilter.sort
    .header=xlYes
    .matchcase=false
    .orienation=xltoptobottom
    .sortmethod=xlPinYin
    .apply
end with
```

Comment: It isn't clear what you are trying to achieve. Plus this code won't even compile. Please describe your input and the expected outcome -- and post your actual code.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delay guys. Also, I should have been more explicit with what I wanted from my code. I really just wanted to copy a sorted range of cells. I was able to use code from a macro that I recorded. Below is the code that ended up working:

```
Range(cells(FR,1),cells(LastRow,5)).select
activeworkbook.worksheets("TR_Tracking").sort.sortfields.clear
activeworkbook.worksheets("TR_Tracking").sort.sortfields.add key:=range( _
    cells(FR,1),cells(lastrow,1)),sorton:=xlsortonvalues,order:=xlascending, dataoption:= _ 
    xlsortnormal
with activeworkbook.worksheets("TR_Tracking").sort
    .setrange range(cells((FR-1),1),cells(LastRow,5))
    .header=xlYes
    .matchcase= false
    .orientation =xltoptobottom
    .sortmethod=xlpinyin
    .apply
end with
```

FR= First Row and LastRow= Last Row in a range I've specified in a separate line of code.